# Show image randomly(horizontal position) sliding up from the bottom of activity

Tags: android, image, random

I would like to show an image come in from different sides(up down left bottom) of my activity, randomly. I want the image to be a gif-animation that slowly shows up and then slowly disappears (like a waving smiley). What would be the easiest way to achieve this? I tried animations but it gets messed up when I try different type of screen resolutions.

Best regards
Joe